# Write output from putStrLn to text file

Tags: haskell, io, ghc

In Haskell. Is there a way to write the output from putStrln (ghc/ghci) for example :

putStrLn (printf $ "this is a example string")

to

writeFile "example.txt" $ "[output from the putStrLn  above]"

Answer (score 4):

Sure, don't call `putStrLn`.

```
writeFile "example.txt" $ printf $ "this is a example string"
```

Of course, for this example the `printf` isn't needed in the first place.

```
writeFile "example.txt" "this is a example string"
```